# Published WIndows Console App fails with System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper..cctor()

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a Windows Console application that accesses our SQL database. This app works fine from VS2019, the debug folder and the release folder. However, if I publish this app, the installed version fails with the exception shown below.

I do note the following differences between the installed location (\AppData\Local\2.0\xxx\yyy) and the \Release folder:

1. The \Release folder has SNI files in the \x86 and \64 directories, but the installed directory is missing this information. ***How do I include this in the manifest? I suspect that this is the main issue causing the exception.***
   [image]
2. The manifest file in the installed location is missing information related to Identity - not sure if this is a concern, but perhaps it is?
   [image]

> Application: SmartRView Configuration.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper..cctor()
>
> Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor()
>
> Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor()

Comment: I didn't solve the problem, but was able to work around this problem by hard-coding the inclusion of the missing files into the installer project target folder.